# Is it possible that smartphones may react differently on the same application?

Tags: android, web-services, smartphone

I have a concern about an application (Android) that I realized whose I don't understand where does the problem.

Basically the application (Android) uses almost everywhere data received from an external BD exchange is from a Web Service (Php).

When I test on my smartphone (Nexus 5 - v 4.4.4), I don't encountered a bug. But when run on two Sony Xperia (v 4.4.2), purchased together, one encounters little bug but the other is all the time it crashes.

I'm a little disappointed, I can not say where it the problem is, if it's my code that is not well managed.

My question is: Is it possible that different smartphones can behave differently on the same application? And if so, how should we handle this?

I'm sorry, my english is not very well. I hope you have understood what I wrote.

Comment: open your application via emulator and check the error code... Give us some more informations

Comment: get some logs from the crashed devices, so someone can help you

Comment: debug it on both failing devices to find out what is happening. your job is to find what is different between the devices and how it is affecting your app.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.

- One reason is the different API version
- and some different implementations from the device manufactors
- some problem I remember are the different root certificates, so if you're using a secured webservice, this might cause the problem. (an ex. for different root CA is 'Baltimore Cybertrust' it's not installed on each device.)

Comment: I encounter some problems with KSoap on several devices. Nexus 4 was the worst device, where I faced with a lot of data transfer errors. You should implement an application crash report to manage all kind of issues.